# Are there non-static equivalents to MSTest's [ClassCleanup] & [ClassInitialize]?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, mstest, system-testing

Are there non-static equivalents to MSTest's [ClassCleanup] & [ClassInitialize]?

I am using MSTest for some system/integration level tests, and I don't want to have to worry about cleaning & initializing the connection in the tests.

Example Code:

```
[TestClass]
public class DefectCreatorTest
{
    private long _cookie;
    private soapcgi _soap;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _soap = new soapcgi {Url = "http://localhost:80/scripts/soapcgi.exe"};
        _cookie = Transaction.Login(_soap);
    }

    [ClassCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        Transaction.Logout(_cookie, _soap);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateDefectTest()
    {
        var result = _soap.Foo();
        Assert.AreEqual("bar", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by non-static? what's wrong with your example code?

Comment: The example code compiles, but will not run.  The method decorated with ClassInitialize needs to be a static method.

Comment: The test would not run because the Initialize method needed to have the TestContext passed into the setup method, even if it's not used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering your question, as far as i know - No, there isn't a non-static equivalent *in MSTest*.

But:

1. looking at your code, there is no reason why `_cookie` and `_soap` shouldn't be made static, along with `Initialize` and `TearDown`. Doing so will let you forget the configuration worries during test writing...
2. If you are willing to "jump ship", The NUnit equivalents for [[ClassCleanup]](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureTeardown&r=2.5.7) & [[ClassInitialize]](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureSetup&r=2.5.8) can be applied to static & instance methods.